# Device owner not being cleared on Android M

Tags: android, adb, device-owner

I wrote a device owner kiosk app that I'd like to remove the device owner status on so I can uninstall it without having to factory reset the device. The following works on Nougat and Oreo, but not Marshmallow for Samsung tablets.

> The specifics of how I'm coding the device owner stuff:

To set the app as device owner, I am running this adb shell command after installing the app:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.dps.myapp/.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

Then when I am trying to remove device owner status and uninstall the app, I am running these shell commands:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.dps.myapp
adb shell am start -n com.dps.myapp/.DeactivateDeviceOwnerActivity
adb shell pm uninstall com.dps.myapp
```

DeactivateDeviceOwnerActivity is an Activity in my app that contains the following code to clear the device owner status:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
if (mDevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Failure! App is still device owner.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
 }
 else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

What is so weird is that my Activity is displaying the Toast that the clearDeviceOwnerApp call worked, but when I run the uninstall command immediately after, I get the "Failure [DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER]" return from it, so obviously the device owner was not cleared for my app.

Does anyone know of any specific differences between Marshmallow and subsequent APIs, regarding device ownership or DevicePolicyManager that would cause this code, that works on Nougat and Oreo, to not work on Marshmallow? When I issue the start command to have DeactivateDeviceOwnerActivity clear the device owner, I'm looking in the system log and I'm not seeing anything that indicates any exceptions occurring. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen some posts talking about a shell command:                                                   adb shell dpm remove-active-admin                                                                                    that doesn't seem to exist in any implementation of adb that I can find. Then I find this page that appears to be the command reference for adb, and there this is:     https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#dpm                   If remove-active-admin is really a dpm attribute, why do I get "unknown command 'remove-active-admin'" if I try that shell command?

Answer (score 0):

I have not faced such an issue on Marshmallow.

This is strange, although I can't give an answer, I will suggest something

1) This might be a bug. So, you can factory reset device and try again.

2) It is very convenient to use the emulator for this type of testing as you can easily just delete and create a new one.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested this multiple times on the Marshmallow tablet, factory resetting it between each failed test.

Comment: Btw 'remove-active-admin' is not a valid command, and did you check device owner status after the toast using adb?

Comment: If remove-active-admin is not a valid command, why is it documented here?:  http://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#dpm                              Yes I checked owner status and it showed that device owner had been released...but still the uninstall failed.

Comment: Further testing showed that the problem all along was with Android Studio...originally when I was testing the simplest approach, to simply install the update over the current version using the shell command "adb install -r", I was getting all kinds of adb errors related to the signing of the apk. I finally realized that after having updated Android Studio, my signed apk was located in a completely different folder, so the one I was testing with wasn't the signed apk I thought it was.Ultimately,figuring this out was key, as you CAN update a device owner app if the update apk is signed the same.

Comment: I made a mistake, device admin is different than device owner.
Yes the command is valid but it only removes device admin privilege.

Comment: Great.
Yea I know we can update owner app signed with the same key.